# Why can't I call a DateTime method on a DateTime object in another class in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, icollection

Ive found a few examples of this problem in other languages such as ruby or php and they seem to indicate that I would need to have some sort of include to support this but I can't exactly figure it out.

I have:

```
private void setLoansView(Member _member)
{

    foreach (Loan loan in _member.Loans)
        {
            this.dt.Rows.Add(_member.Name, // dt is a datatable 
                   loan.BookOnLoan.CopyOf.Title, 
                   loan.TimeOfLoan.ToShortDateString(), 
                   loan.DueDate.ToShortDateString(), 
                   loan.TimeReturned.ToShortDateString());
        }
```

Loan looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Library.Entities
{
    public class Loan
    {
        [Key]
        public int LoanId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime? TimeOfLoan { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? TimeReturned { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Copy BookOnLoan { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Member Loanee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On all my DateTime objects in the `setLoansView()` method I get 'does not contain definition for "ToShortString()".  The Member class has an `ICollection<Loan>` and thats where Im retrieving the loans from.  I can't figure out why I loose access to DateTime's methods when I access them from the `ICollection` though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the type of these properties is not `DateTime`, but `Nullable<DateTime>`. [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not expose such a method.

If you are sure that these dates *will* have a value, interpose `.Value` before `.ToShortDateString()`. If not, you have to decide what should happen in that case.

Comment: Perfect thank you.  So 100% of the time all my DateTime fields will have a value except for `DateTime TimeReturned`.  Is there a clean and efficient way to check that in Add() method?  or will I need to check with hasValue first before the Add()?

Comment: @ChrisShields: The ways to check are the usual conditionals: `if` and the conditional operator `?:`. It depends on what you want to happen if there is no value, e.g. `loan.TimeReturned.HasValue ? loan.TimeReturned.ToShortDateString : "n/a"`.

Comment: thank you again.  I tried having an if statement as one of the arguments but couldn't get the syntax right.  The teranry operator as you suggested however works perfectly.  I'm still trying to get used to using them :)

Answer (score 1):

You have `nullable` `DateTime` objects. You'll need to call `.Value` to get the value (if there is one)

```
loan.TimeOfLoan.Value.ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's nullable, use `.Value` to get those properties (check if null first)

Answer (score 1):

Because your fields are defined as nullable `DateTime?`

Just use `.Value` to access the field's value and you should have your normal DateTime format methods.

Also you should check against null by calling .HasValue

Comment: Thanks for the tip on HasValue :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a nullable DateTime (DateTime?), only the DateTime class has the "ToShortDateString()" method...